# type trait to detect structs with specific methods which have const variants

Tags: c++, templates

I require a trait to detect when a struct has particular methods.

For example, I would like to detect when a struct has the two methods `void foo()` and `void bar(SomeData)`, and false otherwise.

My attempt below works, except when the struct additionally has const variants of the required methods. I would like it to work in this case too as the requirement is only that the two non-const variants are present.

i.e. in the snippet below, `has_methods<T>` is true for `TypeA`, but false for `TypeB`.

How can I adapt this code to work for both `TypeA` and `TypeB`?

```
template<typename T, typename = void, typename = void>
struct has_methods : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_methods<T,
        std::void_t<decltype(&T::foo)>,
        std::void_t<decltype(&T::bar)>> : std::true_type {};

struct SomeData {};

struct TypeA
{
    void foo();
    void bar(SomeData);
};

struct TypeB
{
    void foo();
    void foo() const;
    void bar(SomeData);
    void bar(SomeData) const;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "has_methods<TypeA>: " << has_methods<TypeA>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "has_methods<TypeB>: " << has_methods<TypeB>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Desired output is:

```
has_methods<TypeA>: 1
has_methods<TypeB>: 1
```

Comment: expected output is `11` ?

Comment: yes, I guess I should make that clearer in the question

Comment: generally you want expected signature (or expected usage), not just has any member named like that.

Comment: `struct C { int foo; std::string bar; };` returns true currently too, is it expected?

Comment: Notice that you can use `static_assert(has_methods<TypeA>::value);` to have immediate check (at compile time) instead of using runtime display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `has_methods` isn't actually testing for methods. `&T::foo` matches any member named `foo`. As mentioned in a comment you get a false positive for `struct C { int foo; std::string bar; };`. Fortunately the answer to your question also fixes that.

You can use a `static_cast` to select the desired overload like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_methods<T,
        std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<void (T::*)()>(&T::foo))>,
        std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<void (T::*)(SomeData)>(&T::bar))>> : std::true_type {};
```

Note that a declaration of `SomeData` has to be available (you could make that a parameter of `has_methods`, but for the sake of simplicity I just rearranged the code to define `SomeData` first). Complete example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct SomeData {};

template<typename T, typename = void, typename = void>
struct has_methods : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_methods<T,
        std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<void (T::*)()>(&T::foo))>,
        std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<void (T::*)(SomeData)>(&T::bar))>> : std::true_type {};

struct TypeA
{
    void foo();
    void bar(SomeData);
};

struct TypeB
{
    void foo();
    void foo() const;
    void bar(SomeData);
    void bar(SomeData) const;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "has_methods<TypeA>: " << has_methods<TypeA>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "has_methods<TypeB>: " << has_methods<TypeB>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Output:](https://godbolt.org/z/hcqbj7)

```
has_methods<TypeA>: 1
has_methods<TypeB>: 1
```

(I'd add some negatives to have a more convincing test, but I didn't want to change more than necessary on your code, and partly lazyness ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to specify the method's signature ? So, check for methods with the correct name, regardless of the signature ?

Comment: @nbdy_ from the top of my head,  i wouldnt know how to do it when the method is overloaded.  Maybe open another question,  or is that what you actually wanted to ask?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was asking. I'll open another question if I need it, was just curious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @nbdy_ consider that the information that there is a method with some name alone is not that useful. As an example: https://godbolt.org/z/efGcb7 here `A` has a method called `foo` but you have no way to call it